# solc.loadRemoteVersion is not a function error

Tags: solidity, web3js, solc

I'm trying to load another version of solc using the following code

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var solc = require('solc');
var fs = require('fs');
// getting a legacy version 
const input = fs.readFileSync('contracts/Token.sol').toString();

solc.loadRemoteVersion('0.4.4+commit.4633f3de.Darwin.appleclang', function(err, solcV044) {
    if (err) {
        // An error was encountered, display and quit
    }

    var output = solcV044.compile(input);
    console.log(output);
});
```

but am getting an error `TypeError: solc.loadRemoteVersion is not a function` and I am not understanding why, what am I missing?

EDIT: Not sure what this means but may help identify the issue. When I `console.log(solc)` I get back

```
{ version: [Function],
  compile: [Function: compile],
  useVersion: [Function: useVersion] }
/Users/mcansado/node_modules/solc/bin/soljson-latest.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var Module;if(!Module)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var moduleOverrides={};for(var key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof require==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){if(!Module["print"])Module["print"]=function print(x){process["stdout"].write(x+"\n")};if(!Module["printErr"])Module["printErr"]=function printErr(x){process["stderr"].write(x+"\n")};var nodeFS=require("fs");var nodePath=require("path");Module["read"]=function read(filename,binary){filename=nodePath["normalize"](filename);var ret=nodeFS["readFileSync"](filename
```

Comment: have you installed solcjs?  npm install -g solc

Comment: I have yes. `solcjs --version` returns `0.4.13+commit.0fb4cb1a.Emscripten.clang`

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the version parameter is not correct. How solc handles `loadRemoteVersion`call can be found in your`wrap.js`:

```
  loadRemoteVersion: function (versionString, cb) {
  var mem = new MemoryStream(null, {readable: false});
  var url = 'https://ethereum.github.io/solc-bin/bin/soljson-' + versionString + '.js';
  https.get(url, function (response) {
    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
      cb('Error retrieving binary: ' + response.statusMessage);
    } else {
      response.pipe(mem);
      response.on('end', function () {
        cb(null, setupMethods(requireFromString(mem.toString(), 'soljson-' + versionString + '.js')));
      });
    }
  }).on('error', function (error) {
    cb(error);
  });
},
```

So, to answer your question first, your version should be **'v0.4.4+commit.4633f3de'**, if you replace your '0.4.4+commit.4633f3de.Darwin.appleclang' with this, everything should work out.

Now for future reference:

one quick way to find out is actually type in:
"https://ethereum.github.io/solc-bin/bin/soljson-*YOUR_VERSION_PARAMETER*.js" and then see whether such resource exist (if it doesn't, you will see 404 not found error).

Of course, **a better way** is to find out all released solc version here:
**https://ethereum.github.io/solc-bin/bin/list.json**

For the convenience for people who doesn't like hyperlink, here is a list of all solc:

```
"releases": {
"0.4.16": "soljson-v0.4.16+commit.d7661dd9.js",
"0.4.15": "soljson-v0.4.15+commit.bbb8e64f.js",
"0.4.14": "soljson-v0.4.14+commit.c2215d46.js",
"0.4.13": "soljson-v0.4.13+commit.fb4cb1a.js",
"0.4.12": "soljson-v0.4.12+commit.194ff033.js",
"0.4.11": "soljson-v0.4.11+commit.68ef5810.js",
"0.4.10": "soljson-v0.4.10+commit.f0d539ae.js",
"0.4.9": "soljson-v0.4.9+commit.364da425.js",
"0.4.8": "soljson-v0.4.8+commit.60cc1668.js",
"0.4.7": "soljson-v0.4.7+commit.822622cf.js",
"0.4.6": "soljson-v0.4.6+commit.2dabbdf0.js",
"0.4.5": "soljson-v0.4.5+commit.b318366e.js",
"0.4.4": "soljson-v0.4.4+commit.4633f3de.js",
"0.4.3": "soljson-v0.4.3+commit.2353da71.js",
"0.4.2": "soljson-v0.4.2+commit.af6afb04.js",
"0.4.1": "soljson-v0.4.1+commit.4fc6fc2c.js",
"0.4.0": "soljson-v0.4.0+commit.acd334c9.js",
"0.3.6": "soljson-v0.3.6+commit.3fc68da.js",
"0.3.5": "soljson-v0.3.5+commit.5f97274.js",
"0.3.4": "soljson-v0.3.4+commit.7dab890.js",
"0.3.3": "soljson-v0.3.3+commit.4dc1cb1.js",
"0.3.2": "soljson-v0.3.2+commit.81ae2a7.js",
"0.3.1": "soljson-v0.3.1+commit.c492d9b.js",
"0.3.0": "soljson-v0.3.0+commit.11d6736.js",
"0.2.2": "soljson-v0.2.2+commit.ef92f56.js",
"0.2.1": "soljson-v0.2.1+commit.91a6b35.js",
"0.2.0": "soljson-v0.2.0+commit.4dc2445.js",
"0.1.7": "soljson-v0.1.7+commit.b4e666c.js",
"0.1.6": "soljson-v0.1.6+commit.d41f8b7.js",
"0.1.5": "soljson-v0.1.5+commit.23865e3.js",
"0.1.4": "soljson-v0.1.4+commit.5f6c3cd.js",
"0.1.3": "soljson-v0.1.3+commit.28f561.js",
"0.1.2": "soljson-v0.1.2+commit.d0d36e3.js",
"0.1.1": "soljson-v0.1.1+commit.6ff4cd6.js"
},
 "latestRelease": "0.4.16"
}
```

Hope it helps! Cheers!